# Weakly Convergence of Measures and Uniformly Convergence of Functions

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f_n$ be real valued continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}^N$ with compact supports which converges to a continuous function $f$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}^N$ and $\mu_n$ be Radon measures on $\mathbb{R}^N$ which converges weakly to a Radon measure $\mu$, that is, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\varphi\, d\mu_n=\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\varphi\, d\mu$ for all continuous function $\varphi$ with compact support. Assume that $f$ belongs to $L^1(\mathbb{R}^N,\mu)$ and $L^1(\mathbb{R}^N,\mu_n)$ for all $n$. I want to show that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}f_n\,d\mu_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}f\,d\mu_n = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N}f\,d\mu.$$

I tried to show that via some $f_n$ using the uniformity, but it doesn't work. How is it shown?

Comment: Here, a measure $\mu$ is Radon if $\mu$ is Borel regular and $\mu (K)<\infty$ for each compact set $K$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be true.

Let $\chi_n$ be a positive smooth bump function such that $\|\chi_n\|_{\infty}\leq n^{-N}$,  $\chi_n$ vanishes outside $B(0,2n)$ and $\chi_n$ is equal to $n^{-N}$ on $B(0,n)$. Furthermore, let $\mu_n=1_{B(0,n)} dx$ with $dx$ denoting the Lesbegue measure. Then, trivially, $\mu_n\to dx$ weakly and $\chi_n\to 0$ uniformly by definition. However,

$$
\int \chi_n\textrm{d}\mu_n= n^{-N} dx(B(0,n))=dx(B(0,1))\not\to 0
$$

Comment: You’re right. Thank you. Then, is it true that $\lim\int f\, d\mu_n = \int f\, d\mu$?

Comment: Nope. Imagine $\mu=\delta_0$ and $\mu_n=\delta_0+d n\mathbb{S}_{N-1}$ where $dn\mathbb{S}_{N-1}$ is the surface measure on $n\mathbb{S}_{N-1}$ and let $f$ be any continuous, positive and radially symmetric function which vanishes at infinity but decays like $\|x\|^{-(N-1)}$.